# Google Analytics API is very slow

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I started using the Google Analytics PHP API to retrieve visitor-data for URLs on my website. I got it to work as intended, but it is **very** slow: Getting data for one URL for the last couple of months takes up to a minute - which is very annoying with thousands of URLs. Does anyone have the same issue or a hint on how to make the queries faster?

I do realize there's a quota when using the API, but I'm nowhere near the limit yet.

```
$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$results = $analytics->data_ga->get(
                    $account,
                    $start_date,
                    $end_date,
                    $metrics,
                    $params
);
```

Comment: It could depend on the complexity of the report in question (too many metrics and dimensions). From your code it is not possible to know.

Comment: did you find any solutions?